# ORA 00932- How do I retrieve LONG datatype field in select statement Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to retrieve the views which contain few columns.
I am trying the below Query but as TEXT is LONG datatype ,its not working. I read many articles but cannot get exact solution. Hope I get in this post. Please help!

```
select  t.*
from  ALL_VIEWS t
where t.OWNER = 'OURDB'
and SUBSTR(to_char(T.text),0,3999) like '%Column1%'
and SUBSTR(to_char(T.text),0,3999) like '%Column2%'
and SUBSTR(to_char(T.text),0,3999) like '%Column3%'
and SUBSTR(to_char(T.text),0,3999) like '%Column4%'
and SUBSTR(to_char(T.text),0,3999) like '%Column5%'
```

ORA00932: Inconsistent datatypes; expected CHAR got LONG
Thanks in advance..

Comment: The question is about how to scan view text. An answer must support >32K long conversion.

Comment: Does your condition apply to the column names of the view or the selected tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
dbms_lob.substr(sys_dburigen(view_name, text, 'text()').getclob(),4000,1) like '%Column1%'
```

The list of columns given to sys_dburigen() ending by the one you want to extract, the previous ones must define a unique path.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The result is showing some part of the view but not the complete view. This way I am missing the result . I am using the below Query, expected should return a row but its not because of 4000 I guess. What can we do to retrieve complete view?

Comment: select * from (
select (dbms_lob.substr(sys_dburigen(view_name, text, 'text()').getclob(),4000,1)) as newtext from ALL_VIEWS
)
where  upper(newtext) like '%COLUMN1%'

Comment: Without additional parameters dbms_lob.substr() default to 32767 and 1.
You can also use INSTR on the CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Since a view can exceed 32K, it'll require either materializing to disk using `TO_LOB` or using `dbms_sql.column_value_long` which will involve some rather complex PL/SQL code (it's a lot easier if its < 32K, as you just assign it to a `varchar2` PLSQL variable and it's converted).

First option:

```
create table views_tmp (owner,view_name,text) as 
select owner,view_name,TO_LOB(text) from all_views where OWNER = 'OURDB'
```

Now query it:

```
select  t.*
from  views_tmp t
where T.text like '%Column1%'
and T.text like '%Column2%'
and T.text like '%Column3%'
and T.text like '%Column4%'
and T.text like '%Column5%'
```

Downside is the moment you do that, it's stale - changes to views won't be in this temp table until you re-run the CTAS again. So if you want it be always accurate, you'll need to create your own view using a function employing `dbms_sql` to convert the `long` to `CLOB` on the fly.

Here's some working code for the latter approach. This is for 12.2 to 19c - if you are on something lower, you may need to remove any columns that don't yet exist in your version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dba_views_rectype IS OBJECT (
  TEXT_LENGTH   NUMBER,
  TEXT  CLOB,
  TEXT_VC   VARCHAR2(4000),
  TYPE_TEXT_LENGTH  NUMBER,
  TYPE_TEXT VARCHAR2(4000),
  OID_TEXT_LENGTH NUMBER,
  OID_TEXT  VARCHAR2(4000),
  VIEW_TYPE_OWNER   VARCHAR2(128),
  VIEW_TYPE VARCHAR2(128),
  SUPERVIEW_NAME    VARCHAR2(128),
  EDITIONING_VIEW   VARCHAR2(1),
  READ_ONLY VARCHAR2(1),
  CONTAINER_DATA    VARCHAR2(1),
  BEQUEATH  VARCHAR2(12),
  ORIGIN_CON_ID NUMBER,
  DEFAULT_COLLATION VARCHAR2(100),
  CONTAINERS_DEFAULT    VARCHAR2(3),
  CONTAINER_MAP VARCHAR2(3),
  EXTENDED_DATA_LINK    VARCHAR2(3),
  EXTENDED_DATA_LINK_MAP    VARCHAR2(3),
  HAS_SENSITIVE_COLUMN  VARCHAR2(3),
  ADMIT_NULL    VARCHAR2(3),
  PDB_LOCAL_ONLY    VARCHAR2(3))
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dba_views_tabtype IS TABLE OF dba_views_rectype
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dba_views_ext (in_owner IN varchar2, in_view_name IN varchar2)
  RETURN dba_views_tabtype PIPELINED
AS  
  var_cursor binary_integer;
  var_query varchar2(4000);
  res pls_integer;
  tab_desc dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  var_column_count pls_integer;
  rec_dummy_view dba_views_rectype;
  var_owner dba_views.owner%TYPE;
  var_view_name dba_views.view_name%TYPE;
  var_version_1 integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUBSTR(version,1,INSTR(version,'.')-1)
    INTO var_version_1
    FROM v$instance;
  
  var_query := 'SELECT *
                  FROM dba_views
                 WHERE owner = :owner
                   AND view_name = :view_name';
                   
  var_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(var_cursor,var_query,dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(var_cursor,'owner',in_owner);
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(var_cursor,'view_name',in_view_name);
  
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,1,var_owner,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,2,var_view_name,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,3,rec_dummy_view.text_length);
  dbms_sql.define_column_long(var_cursor,4);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,5,rec_dummy_view.text_vc,4000);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,6,rec_dummy_view.type_text_length);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,7,rec_dummy_view.type_text,4000);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,8,rec_dummy_view.oid_text_length);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,9,rec_dummy_view.oid_text,4000);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,10,rec_dummy_view.view_type_owner,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,11,rec_dummy_view.view_type,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,12,rec_dummy_view.superview_name,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,13,rec_dummy_view.editioning_view,1);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,14,rec_dummy_view.read_only,1);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,15,rec_dummy_view.container_data,1);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,16,rec_dummy_view.bequeath,12);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,17,rec_dummy_view.origin_con_id);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,18,rec_dummy_view.default_collation,100);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,19,rec_dummy_view.containers_default,3);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,20,rec_dummy_view.container_map,3);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,21,rec_dummy_view.extended_data_link,3);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,22,rec_dummy_view.extended_data_link_map,3);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,23,rec_dummy_view.has_sensitive_column,3);
  
  IF var_version_1 >= 19
  THEN
    dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,24,rec_dummy_view.admit_null,3);
    dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,25,rec_dummy_view.pdb_local_only,3);
  END IF;
  
  res := dbms_sql.execute(var_cursor);
  
  WHILE dbms_sql.fetch_rows(var_cursor) > 0
  LOOP
    DECLARE
      var_text_clob clob;
      var_offset pls_integer := 0;
      var_buffer_length pls_integer := 32760;
      var_value_length pls_integer := 0;
      var_long_piece long;
      rec_view dba_views_rectype := dba_views_rectype(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    BEGIN
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,3,rec_view.text_length);
              
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(var_text_clob, false, dbms_lob.call);
        
      LOOP
        dbms_sql.column_value_long(c => var_cursor,
                                   position => 4,
                                   length => var_buffer_length,
                                   offset => var_offset,
                                   value => var_long_piece,
                                   value_length => var_value_length);
                                   
        EXIT WHEN var_value_length = 0;
        
        dbms_lob.append(var_text_clob, var_long_piece);
        var_offset := var_offset + var_value_length;
      END LOOP;
      
      rec_view.text := var_text_clob;
      
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,5,rec_view.text_vc);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,6,rec_view.type_text_length);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,7,rec_view.type_text);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,8,rec_view.oid_text_length);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,9,rec_view.oid_text);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,10,rec_view.view_type_owner);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,11,rec_view.view_type);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,12,rec_view.superview_name);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,13,rec_view.editioning_view);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,14,rec_view.read_only);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,15,rec_view.container_data);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,16,rec_view.bequeath);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,17,rec_view.origin_con_id);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,18,rec_view.default_collation);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,19,rec_view.containers_default);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,20,rec_view.container_map);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,21,rec_view.extended_data_link);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,22,rec_view.extended_data_link_map);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,23,rec_view.has_sensitive_column);
      
      IF var_version_1 >= 19
      THEN
        dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,24,rec_view.admit_null);
        dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,25,rec_view.pdb_local_only);
      END IF;
      
      PIPE ROW(rec_view);
    END;
  END LOOP;

  dbms_sql.close_cursor(var_cursor);
  
  RETURN;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(var_cursor);
    RAISE;
END;
/
  
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_views_ext
AS
SELECT v.owner,
       v.view_name,
       x.*
  FROM all_views v
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(f_dba_views_ext(v.owner,v.view_name)) x
 ORDER BY owner,view_name
/
```

Once that's created (one-time setup), you simply query it:

```
select  t.*
from  ALL_VIEWS_EXT t
where t.OWNER = 'OURDB'
and T.text like '%Column1%'
and T.text like '%Column2%'
and T.text like '%Column3%'
and T.text like '%Column4%'
and T.text like '%Column5%'
```